# Launch concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor with initialization?

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrency, multiprocessing, subprocess

I'm planning to use `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` to parallelize execution of functions. According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html), its `executor` object can only accept a simple function in `map`. My actual situation involves initialization (loading of data) prior to execution of the 'to-be-parallelized' function. How do I arrange that?

The 'to-be-parallelized' function is called in an iteration for many times. I don't want it to be re-initialized each time.

In other words, there's an `init` function that produces some output to this tbp function. Each child should have its own copy of that output, because the function depended on that.

Comment: Can you create an example that shows what the initialization actually is? Is there a reason you can't just create a wrapper around the function you want to parallelize that does the initialization, then calls the function?

Comment: Well, think of initialization as close to `json.load`, the 'to-be-parallelized' function is called in an iteration for many times. I don't want it to be re-initialized each time.

Comment: Ah, ok. And initialization needs to run in the child processes, not the parent?

Comment: FWIW, there's a [patch waiting for review](http://bugs.python.org/issue21423) that I think would do exactly what you want here.

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If using Python 3.7 or above, use [RuRo's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57461497/2073595). This answer is only relevant for earlier Python releases where `concurrent.futures` did not have support for passing an `initializer` function.

---

It sounds like you're looking for an equivalent to the `initializer`/`initargs` options that [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) takes. Currently, that behavior doesn't exist for `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`, though there is a [patch waiting for review](http://bugs.python.org/issue21423) that adds that behavior.

So, you can either use `multiprocessing.Pool` (which might be fine for your usecase), wait for that patch to get merged and released (you might be waiting a while :)), or roll your own solution. Turns out, it's not too hard to write a wrapper function for map that takes an `initializer`, but only calls it one per process:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from functools import partial

inited = False
initresult = None

def initwrapper(initfunc, initargs, f, x):
    # This will be called in the child. inited
    # Will be False the first time its called, but then
    # remain True every other time its called in a given
    # worker process.
    global inited, initresult
    if not inited:
        inited = True
        initresult = initfunc(*initargs)
    return f(x)

def do_init(a,b):
    print('ran init {} {}'.format(a,b))
    return os.getpid() # Just to demonstrate it will be unique per process

def f(x):
    print("Hey there {}".format(x))
    print('initresult is {}'.format(initresult))
    return x+1

def initmap(executor, initializer, initargs, f, it):
    return executor.map(partial(initwrapper, initializer, initargs, f), it)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(4) as executor:
        out = initmap(executor, do_init, (5,6), f, range(10))
    print(list(out))
```

Output:

```
ran init 5 6
Hey there 0
initresult is 4568
ran init 5 6
Hey there 1
initresult is 4569
ran init 5 6
Hey there 2
initresult is 4570
Hey there 3
initresult is 4569
Hey there 4
initresult is 4568
ran init 5 6
Hey there 5
initresult is 4571
Hey there 6
initresult is 4570
Hey there 7
initresult is 4569
Hey there 8
initresult is 4568
Hey there 9
initresult is 4570
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: It might be the problem with wording of my question. But in my case, the function `f(x)` need to have access to the returned result from `initfunc`. And each child should have its own copy. I'm not seeing it possible in this implementation.

Comment: @HeShiming I've edited my answer to demonstrate you can share the result of `initfunc` with each child function in a way that would be easy to translate to `multiprocessing.Pool` w/ the `initializer` kwarg.

Comment: But umm... `initresult` is global. In my case, each child will have to have a separate copy. And I'm not sure if it's picklable, it's not really...

Comment: @HeShiming It's global *per child process*. Look at the output in my answer, there are four different values for `initresult` printed, one for each process in the pool. `initwrapper` only runs in the child processes, so it doesn't need to be picklable.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that. It's surprising that the global is per child. I'll take some time to digest and adapt this solution. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @HeShiming Yes, it's a bit confusing at first glance. The trick is that `initwrapper`, and therefor `do_init`, is only executed inside of the child processes (meaning inside the call to `executor.map`). At that point, all global variables become unique to each child. The `ProcessPoolExecutor` object keeps each child process alive for the entire life of the `Executor` (basically just using a `while <is_pool_alive>`: loop), so that once you initialize the global in the child process, it will be re-used for every single call to `f`.

Comment: This helped me with a related use case where I needed to add an initializer to an executor instance. Rather than messing with the "private" instance variables to inject my initializer and initargs, I used this and it worked great.

Answer (score 12):

As of `Python 3.7`, both the `ThreadPoolExecutor` and the `ProcessPoolExecutor` have the optional `initializer` and `initargs` arguments. Each thread/process will call `initializer(*initargs)` after starting.

See https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/concurrent.futures.html .

Comment: It would be great if the docs showed the signature of the `initializer`. Can it receive a unique task id?

Comment: And would it be possible to also init a database connection as part of the `initializer`? Would make sense to keep it within the process when inserting data.

Comment: How can we pass the output of initializer(*initargs) to each of the task to-be-parallelized?

Comment: There is no signature - it can take arbitrary positional arguments. So yes, you can pass it a unique task id

Comment: Yes, it's possible to init a database connection within the initializer, though I can't say whether I would recommend it without more info

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible to pass the output of initializer to the tasks

Comment: It is "possible" to pass the output of the initializer to the tasks, but you would have to do it manually (inside `initializer` save the results in some global state, then retrieve it in each task).