# How to pass a thread object to the ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrent.futures

The `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` is used by **passing a *function*** to the executor with `executor.submit(my_function)` like so :

```
def my_function():
    print("Hello, world!")

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=50) as executor:
    for t in range(50):
        executor.submit(my_function())
```

But is there a way to **pass a *thread object* instead** ? I have a thread subclass that I would like to use with the executor.

Comment: you will have to over ride [this function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/concurrent/futures/thread.py#L181) with a custom pool executor that way you can use your custom thread object

Comment: Or perhaps you could use the 3.7 initializer function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32130990/python-launch-concurrent-futures-processpoolexecutor-with-initialization

Comment: ^^ that is the better route if the logic can be transferred out of the thread object

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57461497/918959 this was the link i meant to share

Answer (score -2):

try something like this:

```
import concurrent.futures

def my_function(num_time):
    print(f"Hello, world {num_time} times")

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    
    results = [executor.submit(my_function,i) for i in range(50)]
  

    for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(results):
        print(f.result())
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.