# How to share (or exclude from sharing) global variables over multiprocess?

Tags: python, linux, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

In Linux, I understand whenever you fork a child process, the child process gets a copy of the parent process address space.

I don't understand why this is always desirable. The parent process may have global objects that should *not* be shared between parent and child process. Why do we want child process to always get them?

For example, let's say parent process maintains a global database client.

client.py

```
client = None
def get_client():
   global client
   if client is None:
       client = make_new_db_client()
   return client
```

This works fine in my single process application. But could break once I start using multiprocessing.

The problem is that I'm sharing `db_client` object across processes. This database code is actually a 3rd party library. And let's pretend for a second it simply does not work across multiprocesses. So, I create a `db_client` in the parent process, and I'm forcing the child process to use it. It'd fail.

I think the right thing to do is to allow user to selectively pick what gets shared across multiprocess. So in this case, I simply won't share the db_client. Child process would start up and create its own database connection. Everything would work.

But that's not the way Python is designed. global variables are always copied (at least in Linux). Why is it desirable to do that? That seems like it's good sometimes but not always.

Or is there already a way to selectively hide variables from child process?

Comment: This is a really broad question, and has nothing to do with Python specifically. It's about how processes work on most modern operating systems. There are many ways to control this, such as forking before/after other variables are created, or communicating between processes using an IPC mechanism like a pipe. It depends entirely on your application, but since you're writing that, you can presumably pick something that suites your needs. So what are those?

Comment: @bnaecker - thanks for your comment. and yes it is quite a broad question. as for my needs, I start off with an application that makes database queries. The multiprocess element is when I want to use the concurrent.futures.executor to get better performance. I have no idea if the executor would run first or if my main process would run first. this is used for my research environment, so there's no strict requirements on the order of events. I just want the executor to be an extension of my main process.

Comment: Your application is mostly querying a database? Unless you're doing _lots_ of queries, it's unlikely that adding more threads or processes will help. This is textbook IO-bound work, where the application will mostly be waiting for those requests to complete. But if you do want to parallelize the work, it's generally a good idea to start off with totally independent processes, which _communicate_ when needed rather than sharing state. The `multiprocessing` module provides many tools for sending data between processes.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't necessarily always desirable. In many cases it is irrelevant and in some cases confusing.  Many parallel programming mistakes are related to diverging variables and the developer assuming they would be in sync.

Desirability has little to do with this design.  In Linux (and most other Unix variants) Python interpreter creates a subprocess by calling system call `fork()` on C level. This creates an (almost) identical carbon copy of the process calling fork. There are some process bound resources, for example timers, that are not inherited by the child but variables are.

This is the traditional Unix way of creating a process and there are some benefits in it

- The implementation (for those who have developed Python) is there provided by a system call that has survived the test of time.
- It is fast. Very little logic is included in this - memory is just copied over to another location
- Subprocess is viable. In a theoretical mix & match model described in your question it would be possible to create a subprocess that is missing a vital component
- This offers a rapid way of passing data to a subprocess

Consider a subprocess that would not do this. It would be a tabula rasa. By default an empty core capable of receiving executable code and parameters somehow later from the parent that created it.

To make this a running and useful component would require much more work. Both in implementation (you would need to consider every detail) and also execution. Transferring data would require  communication between processes. Initialising the process state to where you want it to be could theoretically require a lot of work, for example reading configuration parameters from a database. And if you need to launch thousands of subprocesses, repeating this work in every process would be **much** slower.

There are of course situations where inheriting global variables will lead you astray. Some developers shun global variables for this very reason. Connectors to external processes or services need to be recreated in children and if global variables represent these, your program can become messy.

One of the reasons parallel programming requires a good design and much attention to detail is exactly this - no programming language can guess what your program wants to do in a subprocess.  What are the inputs and outputs? Does it need to communicate with the parent or another process or computer? How does this happen? Etc.

It is entirely possible parallel processing is not suitable to your task. There are many cases where subprocesses do not help you at all because of the functionality of your application. There are also occasions where apparent multiprocessing related problems can be fixed by redesigning your application. Sometimes it could be wise to handle external communications in the main process and only dispatch calculations etc. to subprocesses. In another case it could be ideal to have the main program do nothing or almost nothing, have every subprocess subscribe independently to external sources and deliver results directly. Many server side applications work this way.

Apologies for a lengthy answer that is almost a non-answer.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Even if I don't use global variables, don't I still have the same problem? Say I have a manager class that keeps track of these database connections. And I happen to initialize the manager in my main process. Now, the moment I spawn child process, the entire virtual memory gets copied. So my manager instance also gets copied to the child process. The manager instance would now have database connections that's useless in the child process, right? So the problem isn't with global variables. It's a general problem, right?

Comment: I am fairly sure you cannot pass a database connection in a manager. Managers work with simpler objects.   Is there a reason why you cannot initialise database connections in the subprocesses?  This is how it is usually done.

Comment: Another way of avoiding duplication of unwanted objects to child processes (for example for memory reasons - pointless to copy over massive structures if the child doesn't need them) is to spawn your subprocesses before you initialise database connection and load massive structures in the parent. You can launch subprocesses before you actually need them.

Comment: you're right. I don't want to pass database connection between processes. And I want to initialize connection in the child process. But how do I do that?  How do I initialize connection in subprocess? Right now, database initialization happens right before access, and connections are stored in a map. Map is empty on first access, so I initialize a connection and store it in the map. All other access will see existing connection in the map, so it'd reuse it. This works in single process, but breaks in multiprocess, since the map is copied to subprocess, and subprocess would try to use it

Comment: as for your second comment about launching subprocess before I need them - I don't think that'd always work with my workflow. I don't always know ahead of time if I need subprocess, as my work is interactive. I use subprocess when I want concurrent.futures.executor to parallelize my work. And my work is interactive because it's part of my research environment. So 1 day, I may not need multiprocess, next day, I may need 4 executors. Next day, I may need 8. And they could all sit in a long running  jupyter notebook instance

Comment: That depends on your db and connection. You could pass all the parameters/credentials needed to connect to a db to the subprocess and just do there what you do in your main process now. This is how I would do it. You could also build a db access class that would be local to every subprocess. It would store the connection in a class variable check if there is a connection and use it if yes, initialise if no. This would replace your map, whatever that is. There is no one true way with multiprocessing.

Comment: I like having a db access class. But how do I make it local to each process? Say I have a db access singleton. My main process may instantiate it some point because the main process needs to access db too. Once that happens, the singleton object is in my parent process virtual memory. Subprocess spins up, sees it, and will use it. So I have the same problem as my map, right? Instead of subprocess seeing a useless map, the subprocess now sees a useless db access object.

Comment: or are you saying I should simply initialize my db access class as the first step after spinning up new process? That's doable. I use concurrent.future.executor to take advantage of multiprocess.  Sounds like what I need is something like this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32130990/launch-concurrent-futures-processpoolexecutor-with-initialization.   Do you agree?